# Drag and drop HTML5 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to drag and drop the box1, box2, box3, box4 but it is not working. I think there is something wrong with the JavaScript function . May i know what can i add or change to make the box drag-gable and can drop?

Everything is in a php file.

Inside the html

```
<div id="box1" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)"> 
<div class="mover" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)"></div> 
</div>
<br>
</br>
<div id="box2" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)"> 
<div class="mover" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)"> </div> 
</div>
<br>
</br>
<div id="box3" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)"> 
<div class="mover" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)"></div> 
</div>
<br>
</br>
<div id="box4" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)"> 
<div class="mover" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)"></div> 
</div>
<br>
</br>
```

In JavaScript.

```
{

document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML=""+shuffling[0];
document.getElementById("box2").innerHTML=""+shuffling[1];
document.getElementById("box3").innerHTML=""+shuffling[2];
document.getElementById("box4").innerHTML=""+shuffling[3];

}

function allowDrop(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
}
function dragWord(dragEvent){
dragEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", 

dragEvent.target.textContent+"|"+dragEvent.target.parentNode.id);
}

function dropWord(dropEvent){ 
var dropData = dropEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text"); 
var dropItems = dropData.split("|"); 
var prevElem = document.getElementById('body'); 
prevElem.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].textContent = dropEvent.target.textContent; 
dropEvent.target.textContent = shuffling[0]; 
dropEvent.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The Box is not moving, cannot be drag. @PitaJ

Comment: @user3773928 - What do want to drag? the boxes or the movers?

Comment: I want to drag the movers,the words inside. @PitaJ